# Order of stacked bar charts differ between ggplot2 and ggiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

I'm building a shiny app that prepares a stacked bar chart with a tooltip showing levels of satisfactions across 3 items and 2 types of respondents. Here's the data that makes up the chart:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Resp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Resp_A", 
"Resp_B"), class = "factor"), Rating = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("DK/NA", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied"
), class = "factor"), Question = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("q14", "q12", "q11"), class = "factor"), count = c(29, 
27, 11, 25, 12, 9, 12, 3, 9, 5, 3, 2, 11, 5, 8, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8
), prop = c(0.644444444444444, 0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.555555555555556, 
0.363636363636364, 0.2, 0.266666666666667, 0.0909090909090909, 
0.2, 0.151515151515152, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0444444444444444, 
0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.242424242424242, 0.0888888888888889, 
0.0888888888888889, 0.242424242424242, 0.133333333333333, 0.242424242424242
), Label = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Label_1", 
"Label_2", "Label_3"), class = "factor"), tooltip = c("<b>Satisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_1\n<b>n=</b> 29\n<b>Percentage:</b> 64%", 
"<b>Satisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 27\n<b>Percentage:</b> 60%", 
"<b>Satisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 11\n<b>Percentage:</b> 33%", 
"<b>Satisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 25\n<b>Percentage:</b> 56%", 
"<b>Satisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 12\n<b>Percentage:</b> 36%", 
"<b>Neutral</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_1\n<b>n=</b> 9\n<b>Percentage:</b> 20%", 
"<b>Neutral</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 12\n<b>Percentage:</b> 27%", 
"<b>Neutral</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 3\n<b>Percentage:</b> 9%", 
"<b>Neutral</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 9\n<b>Percentage:</b> 20%", 
"<b>Neutral</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 5\n<b>Percentage:</b> 15%", 
"<b>Dissatisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_1\n<b>n=</b> 3\n<b>Percentage:</b> 7%", 
"<b>Dissatisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 2\n<b>Percentage:</b> 4%", 
"<b>Dissatisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 11\n<b>Percentage:</b> 33%", 
"<b>Dissatisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 5\n<b>Percentage:</b> 11%", 
"<b>Dissatisfied</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 8\n<b>Percentage:</b> 24%", 
"<b>DK/NA</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_1\n<b>n=</b> 4\n<b>Percentage:</b> 9%", 
"<b>DK/NA</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 4\n<b>Percentage:</b> 9%", 
"<b>DK/NA</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_2\n<b>n=</b> 8\n<b>Percentage:</b> 24%", 
"<b>DK/NA</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 6\n<b>Percentage:</b> 13%", 
"<b>DK/NA</b>\n<b>Question:</b> Question_Text_3\n<b>n=</b> 8\n<b>Percentage:</b> 24%"
), Ord = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4), Question_Text = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Question_Text_2", 
"Question_Text_3", "Question_Text_1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .Names = c("Resp", "Rating", "Question", "count", "prop", 
"Label", "tooltip", "Ord", "Question_Text"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

A couple of additional bits:

```
#Value colours
Labels_Colours <- c("Satisfied" = "#59A14F", "Neutral" = "#76B7B2", "Dissatisfied" = "#F28E2B", "DK/NA" = "#BAB0AC")

#Tooltip feature
tooltip_css <- "background-color:white;font-style:italic;padding:10px;border-radius:10px 20px 10px 20px;"
```

Here's what the chart in `ggplot2` looks like. This chart is exactly what I want my `ggiraph` chart to look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% filter(prop > 0 | is.na(prop)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = ifelse(is.na(prop), 0, prop), fill = Rating)) +
geom_col() +
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(prop), prop, percent(round(prop, 2)))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
scale_fill_manual(values = Labels_Colours) +
coord_flip() +
facet_grid(~ Resp, drop = FALSE) +
labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)
```

[image]

Now, here's my attempt at the final product, using `ggiraph`. The only difference in the code here is that I'm using `geom_bar_interactive` instead of `geom_col`, and of course the last line:

```
library(ggiraph)
mychart <- mydf %>% filter(prop > 0 | is.na(prop)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = ifelse(is.na(prop), 0, prop), fill = Rating)) +
geom_bar_interactive(aes(tooltip = tooltip, data_id = Rating), stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(prop), prop, percent(round(prop, 2)))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
scale_fill_manual(values = Labels_Colours) +
coord_flip() +
facet_grid(~ Resp, drop = FALSE) +
labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)
ggiraph(code = print(mychart), width = 1, point = 4, width_svg = 8, height_svg = 2, tooltip_extra_css = tooltip_css, hover_css = "opacity:0.5")
```

[image]

The "DK/NA" bar somehow switched places with the "Dissatisfied" bar, but my percentage labels and the legend remain in the correct places. What's causing this? I assume this has something to do with the order of the levels in the `Rating` factor, but they appear to be in the correct order. I'm mystified.

Comment: ooops, looks like a serious bug. Thanks (https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/57)

Comment: Thanks @DavidGohel I've actually found a workaround, which you may find useful in your debugging. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks, for now I'm mystified too.

Answer (score 3):

It's about grouping. Aesthetics `tooltip` and `data_id` in `geom_bar_interactive` (or in `geom_bar`, same effect) make grouping different from the grouping of `geom_text`.

> [http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html] By default, the group is set to the interaction of all discrete variables in the plot. This often partitions the data correctly, but when it does not, or when no discrete variable is used in the plot, you will need to explicitly define the grouping structure, by mapping group to a variable that has a different value for each group.

Defining group aesthetic solves the issue (in main *aes* or in *geom_bar*):

```
mychart <- mydf %>% filter(prop > 0 | is.na(prop)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = ifelse(is.na(prop), 0, prop), fill = Rating, group = Rating)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(mapping = aes(tooltip = tooltip, data_id = Rating), stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(prop), prop, percent(round(prop, 2)))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Labels_Colours) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~ Resp, drop = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() 
ggiraph(code = print(mychart), width = 1, point = 4, width_svg = 8, height_svg = 2, tooltip_extra_css = tooltip_css, hover_css = "opacity:0.5")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidGohel points out this is a bug, I've found that the following acts as a workaround:

```
library(forcats)
mydf <- arrange(mydf, Rating)
mydf$tooltip <- fct_inorder(mydf$tooltip)
```

Now, running the `ggiraph` code again:

[image]